# Can my app access a local Evernote database on the iPad?

Tags: ios, evernote

I am developing an app that uses the Evernote API to access a user's notes.  It requires an internet connection and there are various limitations in using the Evernote API.

However, Evernote does give its premium users the option to store all their notes locally on their device.  It would solve quite a few problems for me if I could check for a locally stored Evernote database on the device and then access the user's notes from there rather than the Evernote API.

Does anyone know if there is a way to access that locally stored Evernote database?

Comment: The short answer is 'no'.

Comment: Is there any kind of long answer that ends in at least a "maybe"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Every application is isolated in it's own container and do not have access to other ones.